# Black bar at the bottom of slides

Tags: beamer

Due to restrictions of the prjection space, I cannot use the full frame size, thus I want to add a black bar at the bottom of every slide (underneath the footer). Therefore I effectively reduce the hight of each slide.

Is there an easy way to achieve this while still using a standard beamer theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by modifying the footer. Of course this depends on the theme you use, but in the example below in line 24 you can adjust the `2.25ex` to how thick you need the black bar.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamercolor{back}{fg=black,bg=black}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
        \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%

  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{back}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\author{A.U. Thor}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variant of @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz's idea using tikz.

```
\newlength{\bottommargin}
\setlength{\bottommargin}{3cm}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=\bottommargin,dp=0ex,center]{back}%
        \tikz{\path[fill=black] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\bottommargin);}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }%
  \vskip0pt%
}
```

Comment: Using both a beamercolorbox and a tikz shape feels a bit redundant. If the `back` colour is set, e.g. `\setbeamercolor{back}{bg=black}`,  this will draw a black box over a black box. I'd use one or the other, but not both.

Comment: If you want to go the tikz route, you could simply use `\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \tikz[remember picture]{\path[fill=black] (current page.south west) rectangle (\paperwidth,\bottommargin);}
}
`

Answer (score -1):

You don't add a bar, you change aspect ratio to 16:9.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
```

or...

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
Sets aspect ratio to 16:9, and frame size to 160mm by 90mm.
\documentclass[aspectratio=149]{beamer}
Sets aspect ratio to 14:9, and frame size to 140mm by 90mm.
\documentclass[aspectratio=141]{beamer}
Sets aspect ratio to 1.41:1, and frame size to 148.5mm by 105mm.
\documentclass[aspectratio=54]{beamer}
Sets aspect ratio to 5:4, and frame size to 125mm by 100mm.
\documentclass[aspectratio=43]{beamer}
The default aspect ratio and frame size. You need not specify this option.
\documentclass[aspectratio=32]{beamer}
Sets aspect ratio to 3:2, and frame size to 135mm by 90mm
```

Comment: But this is like adding a black bar at the top and the bottom ;-)

Comment: @Tobi .......XD

Comment: @TroyWoo is right there, I explicitly want to add a bar only on the bottom, as to the top I have lots of space (the beamer is mounted unmovably).